# Making a Linux audio recording device available on a Windows 7 PC over network

Tags: networking, audio, windows, pulseaudio

I would like to use my headset's microphone both on my Linux laptop and a Windows 7 PC simultaneously, for different VoIP applications. I'm currently running Ubuntu with PulseAudio on the laptop to which the headset is connected and I've heard that there are Windows implementations of PulseAudio. Therefore it should theoretically be possible to make the microphone available over my LAN as an PCM stream.

I'm asking now if someone has more detailed insights if this is actually doable with current software or opinions from people with more knowledge about the PulseAudio system if further investigation is likely to pay off. Ideas on doing it in any way without PulseAudio are also acceptable.

Comment: test `gpe-soundbite`  from debian repo.

Comment: I really don't know how that could solve my problem. Seems to be a simple to-file audio recorder. I'm in need of a constant network stream of the microphone input which shows as a regular recording device on the Windows end.